# Compatibility problems with other drivers after formatting system drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, formatting, compatibility

My system currently has 3 drives and I'm wondering should I format and reinstall windows 10 on my system drive if I'll have problems with data stored on my other drives since I've got software/games/etc.. stored on them.
Will I have to reinstall all my programs?

Comment: What problem are you having, here? Windows has a 'Keep my data' reinstall method for fixing OS corruption and such that may fix your problem. If you reformat and install Windows on a newly formatted disk partition, without apply some sort of backup, yes you would need to reinstall all your Windows apps that require installation to work with Windows. **First, backup your data** that's important at a minimum including installed application 'data', and then decide on how to proceed. If you have 3 physical drives, just install apps on "C" and point app data to other drives/partitions.